# GNOME 3 change the wallpaper

Tags: shell, cron, gnome-3

It's the question about changing the wallpaper automatically.
I used GNOME 3.22.3 to be my desktop system and my OS is Debian 9.3.

I wrote a shell called "change_wallpaper.sh" and it's content as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="/home/username/script/ys"
PIC=$(ls $DIR/* | shuf -n1)
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file://$PIC"
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri >> /home/username/script/test
```

This shell will change my desktop background to a image that from /home/username/script/ys and this image was randomly chosen.

The first `gsettings` will change the desktop background.
And the second will record the image path in /home/username/script/test.

I directly executed this shell and then my desktop background was became to the image I wanted.

So this shell could run success.

I had set the shell in `crontab` and it actually had been run every minute....

But only the second `gsettings` run success.

the first `gsettings` hadn't execute.
And I change that line into

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/username/script/ys/01.jpg"
```

It still didn't work.

So I was confused why I used `crontab` would fail.